# Memory leak in iOS, AVPlayer is never deallocated

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, profiling, instruments, avplayer

I used the AVPlayerDemo sample from the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) and wrote my own UI on top of it to play videos selected from a UITableViewController. Now, the problem is that there's a memory leak here somewhere which I can't find out. The problem is that the AVPlayer object is not being dealloced, I guessed this because every time a press back button and select a new video to play, there is a huge jump in the total memory consumed by the app which is show here:

[image: The first time the video is player, the memory usage is 36.6MB]

The first time the video is player, the memory usage is 36.6MB, now for the second time:

[image: Here it has jumped to 58.2MB]

Here it has jumped to 58.2MB, and keeps on increasing every time i go back and play the video again or a different video.

[image]

I have tried using Instruments with Leaks but haven't yet been able to figure out whats wrong with it.

Heres the whole Controller file [code](http://pastebin.com/RYU9M9Tv).

//EDIT

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    if(_player.rate == 1.0){
        [_player pause];
    }

    [idleTimer invalidate];

    if(mTimeObserver){
        [_player removeTimeObserver:mTimeObserver];
        mTimeObserver = nil;
    }
    [_playerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:kStatusKeyT];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:_playerItem];


    _player = nil;
    _playerItem = nil;
    idleTimer = nil;
    _tapGestureRecognizer = nil;
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"DEALLOCING");
}
```

Comment: Sorry but no one is going to go sifting through your entire file...you need to narrow it down by debugging some more (e.g. disable some features and try again or use the allocation view in instruments to determine where it is getting retained, etc)

Comment: I know, I just added the whole thing so that I dont leave out anything that might be causing the leaks.. I'll just copy relevant code and paste it here.

Comment: @FarazHassan have you tried to report ticket to Apple?

Comment: @CAMOBAP I'm sorry I never posted an answer for this. I solved the problem, it wasn't related to the AVPlayer itself. Posting it now. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the idleTimer. When the invalidate method is called on the idleTimer, it doesn't synchronously invalidate the timer, instead, it waits for the next tick(not sure, but does wait for some time) before invalidating and releasing it.

Now, in the meanwhile, the idleTimer reference is being set to nil. On the next tick of the timer, the reference is lost and the memory is never released, and the references propagate all the way to the ViewController and none of its objects are released.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue as you, but I managed to fix the memory leak by calling this on `viewDidDisappear`:

```
self.avPlayer?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved my issue. Really appreciate you posting here.