# iOS AVPlayer play a lot videos and cause memory too high

Tags: ios, memory, avplayer

First of all, thank you for your help.

The Questions:

1.I need to test a lot videos.I wrote two methods to test videos.

2.When playing a video status change, and I set avPlayer = nil and avPlayerItem = nil, i also add the @autoreleasepool {}, but the memory is slowly increased, I used the instruments but I did not find memory leaks, I find a lot questions and did not find a solution.

3.Here is my code：

```
-(void)CheckVideoURlCanPlay{
@autoreleasepool {
    VideoPlayDataObj *videoPlay = [self.needCheckArr objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *str = videoPlay.videoURL;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
    self.playItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playItem];
    self.playLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
    self.playLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
    self.playLayer.frame=CGRectMake(100, 80, 100, 100);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:self.playLayer];
    [self.player play];
    [self.playItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
   }}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context{
@autoreleasepool {

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (self.player.currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
            @autoreleasepool {

                [self.player.currentItem.asset cancelLoading];
                [self.player.currentItem cancelPendingSeeks];
                [self.player cancelPendingPrerolls];
                [self.playItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
                self.playItem = nil;
                self.player = nil;

            }
            [self.needCheckArr removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5];
            [self CheckVideoURlCanPlay];
        }
    }
}
```

}

4.I also tried to relieve the current view, but it does not relieve all. If you play a large number of video memory will be high, the final app will be killed.

5.I wonder if after loading a video, it will produce dirty memory?

this my app start memory:13M
this test some videos and i pop the view :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuDGX.png)
this test some videos again and pop the view :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuUPc.png)

6.Finally, I hope you can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Memory leak in iOS, AVPlayer is never deallocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820725/memory-leak-in-ios-avplayer-is-never-deallocated)

Answer (score 2):

It does not look like you are ever removing the AVPlayerLayer from the view:

```
[self.playerLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
```

Also I cannot see the point of `@autoreleasepool` here, especially if you have ARC turned on (which you almost certainly do!). `@autoreleasepool` is usually only useful when you have ARC turned off, or when you are churning through a lot of memory (as in, many megabytes) in a single main-loop invocation and need to control when they get cleaned up.

Comment: Yes, this is my mistake, but the problem is not here, I try to add to it, but it does not work.

Comment: Yes,I found this code that is causing the problem. self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.playItem]; I don't know how to solve.

Comment: If you do not remove the `AVPlayerLayer` from its super layer, you will leak the AVPlayerLayer and everything that it refers to (including the AVPlayer instance and the AVPlayerItem instance). *That* is your problem.

Comment: I know, but I added  this sentence, the memory is not freed and clean